# Where does the output of catalina.sh go to?

Tags: shell, debugging, tomcat7, ubuntu-14.04

I have a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 installation with tomcat7 (installed with apt-get install tomcat7).
The script /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh produces (logging) output. It does not appear on the console (e.g. when starting tomcat by service tomcat7 restart).
Where does this output go to? Is it logged somewhere?
Where does the output of /etc/init.d/tomcat7 go during system boot?

I am not refering to the output of the Java process itself (it is piped to /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out). Neither /etc/init.d/tomcat7 nor /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh log to catalina.out. If you enter "service tomcat7 restart", you get the output of the tomcat7 script at your console, but not the output of catalina.sh.

Answer (score 1):

Check under the `/var/log/tomcat7` directory.

Comment: It doesn't appear there. catalina.out starts with log entries after catalina.sh, probably only the output of the Java process started from catalina.sh (which is piped there by the java call in catalina.sh).

Answer (score 0):

You can execute `locate catalina.out` in the terminal to find the output file.

Comment: See my comment on the answer above.